# node js and mysql multiple queries and grant that no errors will happen

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node js and mysql and I want to run multiple queries in one query, but I am afraid of due to any unusual reason maybe only first query or only two queries happen and the other occurs errors. so it will be a big mistake in my database.

I think there's a better and professional way rather than I did? even if I need to change sommethings in my databases?

I added ??? for the names.

Example:

```
   
   mysqlConnection.query(`
        INSERT IGNORE INTO ???(??,??) values(???,???);
        UPDATE ??? SET ??? = true WHERE id = ???;
        INSERT INTO ???? (title,body,individual_id) values('???','????','???');
        INSERT INTO ????(title,body,worker_id) values('????','???','????');
        SELECT ????, (SELECT ??? FROM ??? WHERE id LIKE ???) as ??? FROM ??? WHERE id = ???;
        `,(err,rows,fields) =>{
            if(!err){  
                res.send({
                    message: "success"
                })
            }else{
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: "err.sqlMessage"
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: Use the promise-mysql library, then you can put the queries in an array and loop over the array, executing them one at a time with `await`.

Comment: but what if first query succeeded, and the other failed? or happened any errors? does the first one will also succeed ?

Comment: I want to be sure that the 5 queries will succeed if one of them didn't succeed so not doing anything of all queries

Comment: You have to use a transaction whether or not you run them in the same call or multiple calls.